# Unterschied zwischen "vergangen" und "vorbei"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "vorbei" und "vergangen", zum Beispiel:
- der Urlaub ist vorbei
- der Urlaub ist vergangen

Comment: *Vorbei* ist ein Adverb, *vergehen* ist ein Verb.

Comment: _„Vorbei ist vorbei, aber bitte nicht so...“_ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3khvTm8Sg_w

Comment: Danke für das Referenz !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt einen Unterscheid im Sprachteil. *Vorbei* wird hier als [Temporaladverb](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorbei) benutzt. *Vergangen* kann beiderseits als [Adjektiv](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vergangen_Adjektiv) und als Perfekt des Verbes [*vergehen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vergehen) gesehen werden. Bei der zweiten Interpretation könnte man den Satz noch mit einem Adverb ergänzen, zum Beispel

> Der Urlaub ist **gut** vergangen.

Comment: Danke schön für deine Antwort !